# Role based authorization causing me infinite loop React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried implementing a role based authorization, but everytime I go into a page that I've added a that authorization, it keeps refreshing.
these are my routes

```
{ url: "ecom-orders", component: Orders, role:'admin' },
{ url: "ecom-myorders", component: Myorders, role:'user' },
{ url: "ecom-ordersbyuser/:userid", component: OrdersByUser },
{ url: "AddProduct", component: AddProduct, role:'admin' },
```

this is where I'm mapping them and calling the authorization function :

```
                   <Switch>
                     {routes.map((data, i) => (
                        data.role == "checklogin" ? (
                           <CheckLogin
                           key={i}
                           exact
                           path={`/${data.url}`}
                           component={data.component} 
                        />                                          
                        ) : data.role == "admin" ? (
                        <CheckAdmin
                           roles={['2']}
                           key={i}
                           exact
                           path={`/${data.url}`}
                           component={data.component} 
                        />
                        ): data.role == "user" ? (
                           <CheckUser                           
                           roles={['1']}
                           key={i}
                           exact
                           path={`/${data.url}`}
                           component={data.component}                           
                        />
                        ): (
                           <Route
                           key={i}
                           exact
                           path={`/${data.url}`}
                           component={data.component}                           
                        />
                        )
                     ))}
                  </Switch>
```

And these are my authorization functions:

```
const CheckUser = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => (
      <Route
        {...props}
        render={routeProps => {
           let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ConnectedUser"))[0]['Role'];
          // Do all your conditional tests here
          return (item !== null && item == 1) ? (             
            <Component {...routeProps} />                      
          ) : (
            <Redirect to="/page-error-404" />  
          );
        }}
      />
    );
    const CheckAdmin = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
         let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ConnectedUser"))[0]['Role'];
          // Do all your conditional tests here
          return (item !== null && item == 2) ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (            
            <Redirect to="/page-error-404" />  
          );
        }}
      />
    );
```

What's causing the infinite loop so the page keeps just refreshing itself ?

Comment: Are you checking access on your 404 page? Also, 401 is access denied, 404 is page not found.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I am, if the item is null it redirects me fine. problem is when the item is set.